# appending to array in tcl

Tags: arrays, key, tcl, hashtable

I am passing the name of the array, key and value. If the array exists but the key is not defined in the array, I am trying to append the key-value pair to the array.

How does one append a pair to an array in tcl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a key/value pair to a Tcl array, just do:

```
set theArray($theKey) $theValue
```

You could also use:

```
append theArray($theKey) $theValue
```

Which will create the key/value pair if they don't exist and append to the value in the array if they do.

If you're passing in the various things as arguments, the procedure might look like:

```
proc appendValueToArray {arrayName keyName valueToAppend} {
    upvar 1 $arrayName theArray
    append theArray($keyName) $valueToAppend
}
```

Comment: Remember that Tcl's arrays are _associative_ arrays.